# I am trying to get sejda console to work on my Windows8 machine, getting java error

Tags: java

When running the sejda-console command it tells me that "java" is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: Is Java installed on your machine? If not you can find it here (http://www.java.com)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add java path to environment variable

> variable name: "PATH"
>
> variable value: PATH_OF_BIN_OF_YOUR_JAVA_INSTALLATION (eg: c:\program files\java\jdk1.7_13)